# Download data using intermediate/transit server

Tags: linux, data-transfer

I need to download 500TB worth of files and folder with an intermediate server between the source and destination. However the intermediate has only 10TB of free space available to use. The source and destination only have rsync, scp and bbcp available. Binaries can be downloaded and executed if needed. The intermediate is more flexible and can install from package repos as well. But commands can only be issued from the destination as it is behind a vpn. Lastly, the host and destination have redhat enterprise linux whereas the intermediate has ubuntu 18.04. What would be the simplest and most efficient way to automate and accomplish this download without the need for a complex script?

Answer (score 9):

`scp -J` and `scp -o ProxyJump` (equivalents) allow one to SCP from/to remote servers through intermediate/proxy hosts (multiple can be specified).

As an example:

```bash
scp -J ${proxy_user}@${proxy_host} \
    ${remote_user}@${remote_host}:${remote_path} .
```

Or, if non-standard SSH ports (i.e., not `22`) are in use:

```bash
scp -J ${proxy_user}@${proxy_host}:${proxy_port} \
    -P ${remote_port} \
    ${remote_user}@${remote_host}:${remote_path} .
```

Comment: Thanks! How will the download occur? Will it first download the complete folder to the intermediate and then transfer it over to the destination or will it download each folder/file and transfer it? I only have 10TB on the intermediate

Comment: @ps5460 When using a jump host with any SSH tool, the jump host just routes traffic (and possibly logs traffic). IOW, this is like connecting to a web server through a transparent proxy that does no caching and stores nothing locally.

Comment: This approach can also be used with `rsync`. Syntax for that looks like `rsync -e "ssh -J ${proxy_user}@${proxy_host}" ${remote_user}@${remote_host}:${remote_path}`. Given the size of the transfer, I would probably lean towards using rsync for this instead of just SCP, as that then allows for resuming transfers.

Comment: @ps5460 The download will occur from the source to the destination; the relay will relay each packet immediately as it arrives. Because it is immediate, `ssh -J` can be used for interactive sessions as well (you could ssh to a destination and run commands).

Comment: Thanks! By the way I have a related question posted here - https://superuser.com/questions/1734278/gnu-parallel-rsync-via-intermediate-server

Comment: "Comment" added. :-)