# GNU parallel & RSync via intermediate server

Tags: linux, rsync, gnu-parallel

I'm trying to spawn multiple rsync instances with gnu parallel to download via an intermediate server. This is the command I use -

```
cat ~/filelist | parallel --will-cite -j 5 --verbose --progress --line-buffer --keep-order rsync -avrhP -e "ssh -J intermediateUserID@intermediateIP" sourceUserID@sourceIP:{} ~/scratch/quicktest/
```

But I get the following error -

> rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1354)
> [sender=3.1.3] local:0/728/100%/0.0s rsync -avrhP -e ssh -J
> intermediateUserID@intermediateIP
> sourceUserID@sourceIP:/source/directory/path
> /destination/path/
> local:1/728/100%/0.0s Unexpected remote arg:
> sourceUserID@sourceIP:/source/directory/path

Seems like gnu parallel for some reason removes the quotes after -e. How can I make it include the quotes and basically make the proxy jump work with GNU parallel and rsync?

Answer (score 1):

Bash is parsing your command line and feeding `ssh -J intermediateUserID@intermediateIP` as a single 11th argument to `parallel`.  In turn, `parallel` is passing that string unquoted as several arguments to `rsync`.  What you likely want is to pass that argument with internal quotes.

For example:

```bash
cat ~/filelist \
    | parallel --will-cite -j 5 --verbose --progress --line-buffer --keep-order \
        rsync -avrhP \
        -e "'ssh -J intermediateUserID@intermediateIP'" \
        sourceUserID@sourceIP:{} \
        ~/scratch/quicktest/
```

For reference, your command line was: `cat ~/filelist | parallel --will-cite -j 5 --verbose --progress --line-buffer --keep-order rsync -avrhP -e "ssh -J intermediateUserID@intermediateIP" sourceUserID@sourceIP:{} ~/scratch/quicktest/`.

*P.S.  Your command should work if you're using passphrase-less public key authentication (and have already accepted and/or bypassed knownhost-files).  Otherwise, you'll encounter challenges with parallelized processes (i.e., `rsync`/`ssh`) wanting input and, with `--tty`, `parallel` assumes also `-j1 -u`.  To overcome that challenge, consider using `pssh` instead of `parallel` w. `rsync` or consider integrating `sshpass` into your existing command-line.*